# How To Use AND Operator Between STRING values in if Statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I want to add more than 1 tag in my if else statement below `[if (hit.transform.gameObject.tag.Equals("object"))]` so how can I use AND operator to add more tags:

```
public class ToolTip : MonoBehaviour {

public RectTransform tooltip;
public Text tooltiptext;
public Vector2 offset;
public LayerMask lm;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, lm))
    {
        if (hit.transform.gameObject.tag.Equals("object"))
        {
        tooltip.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        tooltiptext.text = hit.transform.name;
        tooltip.position = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x + offset.x,
            Input.mousePosition.y + offset.y);

    }

    }

    else
    {
        tooltip.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        tooltiptext.text = null;
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well it makes no sense to me to check if an object has two tags? Do you have two objects and you want to check if either one is hit?

Comment: i have 6 objects with different tags

Comment: Then you have to check it with or not and whether if you hit one of them or not :) and would work if you hit all 6 of them which i do not think possible

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2) method, because in this way I don't have to repeat `hit.transform.gameObject.tag.Equals` in my if statements anymore:

```
(new[]{ "object" , "object2" }).Contains(hit.transform.gameObject.tag)
```

Just don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` to your using directives.

Answer (score 1):

While answers so far tell you how to use the AND logical operator &&, what you actually want is to use OR logical operator ||. As there can only be one tag assigned to object, comparisons using AND will always return false, what you want is trigger the action if the tag is either one or the other (it will never be both)

Answer (score 0):

With the && operator you can add more AND statements. For instance:

```
 if ((hit.transform.gameObject.tag.Equals("object")) && (hit.transform.gameObject.tag.Equals("object2")))
 {
        tooltip.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        tooltiptext.text = hit.transform.name;
        tooltip.position = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x + offset.x,
            Input.mousePosition.y + offset.y);

  }
```